# Simple questions concerning the center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following : Let $G$ be a group of order $6$ such that $G$ has only two non singleton conjugacy classes $C(a_1)$ and $C(a_2)$. Find the order of $Z(G)$.

Here's what I tried: we know by Lagrange's theorem $[G:N(a_i)]|N(a_i)|=|G|$ and $[G:N(a_i)]=C(a_i)$ and since $C(a_i)$ are have cardinality greater than $1$ then $[G:N(a_i)]=2$ or $3$ (by $[G:N(a_i)]|N(a_i)|=|G|$ ) the case where $[G:N(a_i)]=6$ is ignored since we get a contradiction by the class equation $|G|=[G:N(a_1)]+[G:N(a_2)] + |Z(G)|$ and $[G:N(a_2)]>1$ then $|G|>6$. Now if $[G:N(a_1)]=2$ and $[G:N(a_2)]=3$ we get $|Z(G)|=1$ , there is one similar case the remaining two are if $[G:N(a_1)]=[G:N(a_2)]=3$ or $[G:N(a_1)]=[G:N(a_2)]=2$. The first one gives $|Z(G)|=0$ which is impossible since $e\in Z(G)$ .If $[G:N(a_1)]=[G:N(a_2)]=2$ then $|Z(G)|=2$ . Then $|G/Z(G)|=|G|/|Z(G)|=3$ which is a prime hence $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian $\implies$ $6=|G|=|Z(G)|$ which is a contradiction.

This got me thinking the condition that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic does not require $|G|=|Z(G)|$ but it gives that $G$ is abelian which implies that $|G|=|Z(G)|$ .Besides in the above problem ,this also happens showing that any group of order $p^2$ is abelian (where $p$ is any prime) when $|Z(G)|=p$ we get an abelian group but $G\neq Z(G)$.

My questions are: Did I solve the problem correctly? (If you know of a simpler way please state it because I feel that my method is rather long)

Can any one explain to me why does what I wrote in the third part of this question happen?

Comment: "Let G be a group of order 6 such that G only has two non singleton classes" is not a problem, it's a list of assumptions. Am I missing something? I also don't know what a singleton class is; is $C(a_1)$ the centralizer of $a_1$?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot the question I'll add it

Comment: @Tyler I don't know that , I'm also required to use the class equation to solve this.

Comment: The reasoning looks OK to me, then! I'm not sure how much detail you have to give in your proof. Did you use Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: @TylerBailey I think I've made my proof hard to read. I'll fill in the gaps.

Comment: I feel like my proofs look the same way before I re-write them to turn them in! Feel free to post your own complete solution to answer this question if you'd like.

Comment: @Tyler Actually I'm studying for an exam and this is a practice problem which is really bugging me.

Comment: There are exactly two groups of order six, and one of them is abelian soit does not fit your conditions... I am almost sure proving this is easier than your proof!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I have not taken that. I will look into it, but I also want to know if my method is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order six which has exactly two non-singleton conjugacy classes, and let $a$ and $b$ be the number of elements in this classes. In particular, it is not abelian.

From the class equation, we know that $|Z(G)|+a+b=6$, so $Z(G)$ has at most two elements because $a\geq2$ and $b\geq2$.

Suppose $Z(G)$ is not trivial, so that it has $2$ elements. Then $G/Z(G)$ has $3$ elements, and it is therefore cyclic. This is impossible, because we know that a group which when quotiented by itz center is cyclic is abelian, and $G$ isn't.

We see, then, that $Z(G)=1$

Comment: This is way better and clearer, thank you very much!